# torch.nn.embedding has run time error

Tags: python, pytorch, word-embedding

I want to use `torch.nn.Embedding`. I have followed the codes in the documentation of embedding command.
here is the code:

```
# an Embedding module containing 10 tensors of size 3
embedding = nn.Embedding(10, 3)
# a batch of 2 samples of 4 indices each
input = torch.LongTensor([[1,2,4,5],[4,3,2,9]])
embedding(input)
```

The documentation says that you will receive this output:

```
tensor([[[-0.0251, -1.6902,  0.7172],
         [-0.6431,  0.0748,  0.6969],
         [ 1.4970,  1.3448, -0.9685],
         [-0.3677, -2.7265, -0.1685]],

        [[ 1.4970,  1.3448, -0.9685],
         [ 0.4362, -0.4004,  0.9400],
         [-0.6431,  0.0748,  0.6969],
         [ 0.9124, -2.3616,  1.1151]]])
```

but I don't receive this output. instead I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mahsa/PycharmProjects/PyTorch_env_project/PyTorchZeroToAll-master/temporary.py", line 12, in <module>
    embedding(input)
  File "/home/mahsa/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 224, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mahsa/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/sparse.py", line 94, in forward
    self.scale_grad_by_freq, self.sparse
RuntimeError: save_for_backward can only save input or output tensors, but argument 0 doesn't satisfy this condition
```

Can anybody guide me about this error? and about the work of `torch.nn.Embedding`?

Comment: Post your full error Trackback here so we can help you.

Comment: Maybe problem is torch version, try to check your torch version with doc you using.

Comment: I changed this line "input = torch.LongTensor([[1,2,4,5],[4,3,2,9]])" with "input = autograd.Variable(torch.LongTensor([[1,2,4,5],[4,3,2,9]]))" and the problem was solved. But I didn't understand the meaning of 3 and 10 in the first line of my code "embedding = nn.Embedding(10, 3)". what are they?

Comment: The documentation is for updated version of PyTorch `0.4` while it seems that you are running an older version, maybe `0.3.1`. Try upgrading your PyTorch, or, wrapping your tensor creation with `torch.autograd.Variable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if we change this line:

```
input = torch.LongTensor([[1,2,4,5],[4,3,2,9]])
```

with this:

```
input = autograd.Variable(torch.LongTensor([[1,2,4,5],[4,3,2,9]]))
```

the problem is solved!